# How to get first element when "First" Method is not suported in EntityQuery to Filter

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm using DomainServiceClass and EF in my Silverlight Application:
I got problem. When i try to call DomainService.Load() method with a query have contains ".First()" method to filter, i got Exception ".Fisrt() is not supported..."

Example: 1 Category have many Related Product

```
DomainServiceContext _Service = new DomainServiceContext();
EntityQuery<Category> _query = from item in _Service.GetCategoryQuery()
                               where item.Products.First().IDProduct == 1
                               select t;
_Service.Load(
_query,
LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,
LoadOp=>
{
if(LoadOp.HasErrors)
  {
    //Do something
  }
else 
  {
    //Do something
  }
},
null);
```

My condition have to get first record to compare with something, how can i do that?

Comment: Also try `item.Products.Any(p => p.IDProduct == 1)` Assuming that the records are unordered, and you use `First()` to get the only record, `Any()` should give you an equivalent result.

Comment: did you add using System.Linq;

Comment: sorry, i updated my question.
i'm using linq to get data from Client by DomainService with some filter

Comment: @Sergey Boiko: i added 
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
using System.Linq;

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: above code is example i want to ask.
In my application, i have to get Last record in ordered list to compare with something